# GTK applications looking ugly after an upgrade to Fedora 24. Why?

Tags: linux, fedora, gtk, appearance

Here's an example of what pavucontrol looks like on my system after an update to Fedora 24:

[image]

As you can see, widgets have no spacing and some are even missing altogether - in this example, I have no volume scrollbar (it should look more like [this](https://community.linuxmint.com/img/screenshots/pavucontrol.png)). I'm using XFCE. According to lxappearance, I'm using widget theme Xfce-4.6. What could be wrong?

Comment: So it's looking "ugly" huh!! Must be one ugly looking mug... What part exactly is looking ugly to you though since what's ugly to one may may be beautiful to another man (e.g. like an ugly man).

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT: added some details here: https://superuser.com/posts/1119348/revisions

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is caused by a misconfiguration of the `HiDPI` option of your theme. The quickest solution is to change to a theme that straight up disables that. Otherwise you need to change the dpi settings, for xfce seems to be `Settings Manager → Appearance → Fonts`, but might not fix all the wrong spacing

Comment: Thanks for the anxwer untore! Is there a simple way to test it? It seems to happen across all themes and also for GTK programs ran within `kdesu`.

Comment: type `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 0` in console to disable hidpi and put `Xft.dpi: 96`  in your `~/.Xresources` and restart your X session